# Error in equation

Tags: equations

I wrote the code of this image but it doesn't work? Any help

[image: equation]

```
\begin{equation}
F(n) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    n/2 & \quad \text{if $n$ is even}\\
    -(n+1)/2 & \quad \text{if $n$ is odd}
  \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: What does not work? What error messages do you get? Do you have faulty output? A tip: Instead of the `array` environment, you can use the `cases` environment (it includes the left brace automatically). Do you load the `amsmath` package for the `equation` environment?

Comment: Thanks Alot, the error message was not in this code, and i managed to fix it

Comment: On that basis, I'm closing as 'too localized'

Answer (score 2):

As stated by sherif Haggag, you can use the `dcases` environment:

```
\[
 f(n) = \begin{dcases*}
        n/2  & if $n$ is even\\
        -(n+11)/2 & when $n$ is odd
        \end{dcases*}
\]
```

Adapted from [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics)